# Find the position of the first non zero value in a vector starting from one given position

Tags: matlab

If I have a binary vector `x`:

```
x = [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0];
```

and a position (linear index) `p`:

```
p = 7;
```

I want to find the position of the first non zero value in this vector `x` starting from the position `p` (and moving in positive direction):

```
x = [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0];
                   ↑                               ↑
           %starting position (7)         %position to find (24)
```

It can be done with a for loop:

```
for ii = p:length(x)
    if x(ii)~=0
        ind = ii 
        break
    end
end
```

But is there a smarter/more efficient way to reach the same result ?

Comment: Ho ok -_-, I've just noticed that we can use: `find(x(p+1:end),1)+p` (positive direction) and  `find(x(p:-1:1),1)` (negative direction)

Comment: correction: `p-find(x(p:-1:1),1)` (negative direction)

Comment: For very large `x`, the loop will be the most efficient implementation!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Is that true? Does MATLAB actually create a new vector, or does it simply pass the subarray by reference (copy on write)? `find(x, 1)` does seem to stop when the first non-zero element is found rather than searching the entire array, at least in Octave.

Comment: @beaker: `y = x(p:end)` copies the data, MATLAB arrays never reference sub-arrays, as far as I know. In principle there could be an optimization that skips copying for `find(x(p:end))`, but I don't think this is implemented. In any case, this is easy to test... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, assigning a value to a new variable copies it, but that's not what we're doing here. We're passing a variable to a function, which normally doesn't trigger a copy unless you write to the variable. And it's easy to test if you have MATLAB, which I don't. ;)

Comment: @beaker: I've added a test. I think it's clear that the array gets copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick timing test:

- `method1` is the loop in the OP.
- `method2` is the fixed version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56037552/7328782), using `find` and copying the array.
- (I didn't add the `bwconncomp` answer because it's significantly slower).

Test results depend, of course, on the expected number of elements to visit before a non-zero element is found, as well as on the array length `n`. `q` is the location of the first non-zero element. I always take `p=10`. Times in seconds:

```
n       q       method1     method2
------  ------  ----------  ----------
1e3     p+5     5.9714e-07  2.8644e-06
1e3     end-5   3.9806e-06  3.3714e-06
1e6     p+5     6.4526e-07  0.0027
1e6     end-5   0.0029      0.0033
```

Thus, the `find` method has a running time dictated by the overhead of copying the array and calling `find`, whereas the loop method time is dictated by how many array elements one needs to visit to find the first non-zero element.

---

Test code:

```matlab
N = 1e6;
p = 10;
x = zeros(1,N);
%x(p+5) = 1;
x(end-5) = 1;
timeit(@()method1(x,p))
timeit(@()method2(x,p))


function ind = method1(x,p)
for ii = p:length(x)
    if x(ii)~=0
        ind = ii;
        break
    end
end
end

function ind = method2(x,p)
ind = find(x(p:end),1) + p-1;
end
```

Comment: I have to say, I'm surprised, but not shocked ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can pick the array from p and use find.

```
x = [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0];
p = 7 ; 

iwant = find(x(p:end)>0,1)
```

Comment: I've just noticed that :p, you still need to add `p-1` at the end to get the right index

Comment: Here's the doc to the find function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Comment: Or `iwant = find(x & (1:numel(x))>=p,1)`

Comment: @Siva I will accept this answer if you take into account my previous comment.

Comment: It is not necessary to do `>0` (this slows it down), and your index returned is the index into the cut-down array, not the original array. You need to add `p-1` as indicated by @obchardon.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **bwconncomp()** function. This functions will give you the ones position in the given array. The info for the positions will be held in the **islands.PixelIdxList**. So the position to find (after p of course) is the first element of the **ptf** array:

```
islands=bwconncomp(x);
positions=[cell2mat(islands.PixelIdxList(:))];
ptf=positions(positions(:)>p);
```

Comment: Nice and creative solution!

Comment: Why not just `positions = find(x);` instead of the first two lines?

Comment: @LuisMendo this could work too. I am just suggesting an alternative solution very useful to binary images situations!